# How is the gamma distribution used in the model developed by the Imperial College COVID-19 Response Team?

Tags: modeling, stochastic-processes, gamma-distribution, epidemiology

The Imperial College COVID-19 Response Team report mentions, "Individual infectiousness is assumed to be variable, described by a gamma distribution with mean 1 and shape parameter 0.25."  With that said, it is still unclear to me how this is used.  I would assume random sampling from this distribution but what does that then supply to the model/simulation? The gamma-distributed probability of infecting another person?  Or not a random variable but probability of infecting another person over time?  Or does it have something to do with reproducibility?

Answer (score 0):

The model from Imperial College is an [agent based model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model). So probably that individual infectiousness will be some factor in further calculations for the probability of transmission during contacts between the different individuals.

I could not exactly trace back the description of the model or the methods. There is a lot of referencing backwards in time. In the supplemental information of this reference https://doi.org/10.1038/nature04017 a description is given of infectiousness being either 0 or 1. This infectiousness is used in the computation of the probability for an individual to get infected, which is some sort of weighted sum of several paremeters among which infectiousness of the individuals that one encounters plays a role.

Comment: Most likely, that's the link: https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/medicine/sph/ide/gida-fellowships/Imperial-College-COVID19-NPI-modelling-16-03-2020.pdf

Comment: That is correct.  On page 4.